# Using the PictureSelector library - "Cannot resolve symbol GlideEngine"

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using this picture selecting library

https://github.com/LuckSiege/PictureSelector

but I'm having trouble even getting the basic example to work.

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'io.github.lucksiege:pictureselector:v3.0.9'
}
```

Dependencies added.

Using the sample code:

```
PictureSelector.create(this)
   .openGallery(SelectMimeType.ofImage())
   .setImageEngine(GlideEngine.createGlideEngine())
   .forResult(new OnResultCallbackListener<LocalMedia>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(ArrayList<LocalMedia> result) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancel() {

     }
});
```

Getting a `"Cannot resolve symbol GlideEngine"`

[image]

I tried invalidating and clearing caches, cleaning and rebuilding. Still not sure why it's happening.

Using it without the line `.setImageEngine` gives me the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: imageEngine is null,Please implement ImageEngine
        at com.luck.picture.lib.basic.PictureSelectionModel.forResult
```

Have tried googling `"Cannot resolve symbol GlideEngine"` and searching the library's github issues, but no such issue. Quite lost at this point. Anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm dumb or they just have bad documentation because no where does it say you need to create your own `GlideEngine.Java`

Thanks to this post

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/914/how-to-create-an-image-video-picker-with-preview-using-the-matisse-library-for-android-with-glide-4

[image]